# Setting ScrollBehaviors globally for PageView independent of ListView

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to set the `scrollBehavior` of a `PageView` globally, without affecting other ScrollBehaviors?

I know I can do the following to set the scrollBehavior of all scrolling elements globally

```
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
    dragDevices: {
      PointerDeviceKind.touch,
      // PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
    },
  ),
  child: MaterialApp(),
);
```

However, this effects a PageView and a ListView equally. I want to disable scrolling by mouse drag for everything except the PageViews but I don't want to have to set the property for every single PageView in my app.

The best solution I can come up with would be to create my own PageView that extends the PageView but then I need to remember to always use my own Widget.